# "on understanding" vs "in understanding"

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence why is the preposition "on" used? I would use "in" but to be honest I don't know why. How do I know which one is the correct to use?

> A front end developer will often focus heavily on understanding HTML,
>   CSS, and JavaScript since these languages live in the browser.

Comment: "On" is the preposition for "focus": "focus on"

Comment: What @Stefan said. Change the verb, and the preposition changes with it: _A front end developer will often need help in understanding HTML, CSS, and Java Script._ (In this case, it's better to look backwards than forwards.)